# Deserialize struct which contains Weak

Tags: rust, serde

I have a struct which contains a weak ref to a pre-existing Arc. Is there a way for me to pass this Arc to the struct's deserializer, without writing my own deserializer/visitor?

Example struct / deserialize:

```rust
struct SomeGlobal;

#[derive(Deserialize)]
struct SomeState {
  pub a: i32,
  pub b: Weak<SomeGlobal>,
};

fn magic_deserialize(value: serde_json::Value, g: Arc<SomeGlobal>) -> Result<SomeState, ...> {
  // what goes here?
}

#[test]
fn example() {
  let g = Arc::new(SomeGlobal);
  let value = json!({
    "a": 5
  });

  let state = magic_deserialize(value, g.clone()).unwrap();

  // state.a == 5
  // state.b == weak ref to g
}
```

Comment: Since you don't seem to be serializing or deserializing `SomeState.b`, it's probably a better idea to put that into a struct you're not deserializing, so `SomeState` could simply not be `Deserialize` but contain a second struct that is `Deserialize` but doesn't contain `b`.

Comment: In my actual case, the state struct is a handle to an entry in a global hashmap wrapper. The state struct needs to contain a weak ref to the global hashmap and the id of the entry because it has a few proxy methods that fetch the entry then call the corresponding method.

While I could separate the two, it would complicate everything because the handle is supposed to be opaque.

Comment: Since you're already calling `magic_deserialize`, that function can create your `SomeState` struct itself, no need for `SomeState` itself to be `Deserialize`, right?

Comment: It's used in other structs which are themselves `Deserialize` and `Serialize`. If there's a way to deserialize `SomeState` by just specifying an attribute in the parent struct, it doesn't need to be `Deserialize`. I'm mainly trying to avoid lots of boilerplate, since I don't want to force every parent struct to write their own `Deserialize` etc implementation and I don't want to hack something together to partially load the parent struct, then load all the handles.

Answer (score 1):

Since `Weak<T>` implements `Default`, you can simply annotate `b` with `#[serde(skip)]` to have serde skip serializing this field, and set it to default when deserializing.

```rust
#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct SomeState {
    pub a: i32,
    #[serde(skip)]
    pub b: Weak<SomeGlobal>,
}
```